# InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal Exception

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kmm

I'm very new to the Kotlin Multiplatform and Swift language, I have a problem with KMM only the iOS part, I have successfully run this on Android but it fails on IOS due to concurrency issues.

Kotlin code snippet :

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
    suspend fun getResponse(data: String): String {
        var response: String
        
        client.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (_, body) ->
                    when (context.response.status) {
                        HttpStatusCode.OK -> response = body as String
                    }
                }
                response = client.post(BASE_URL) {
                    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                    body = data
        }
        return response
    }
```

iOS code snippet :

```
@State var response: String = ""

    Button("Click") {
        Repository().getResponse(data: "hello world") { data, error in
            if data != nil {
                response.self = "\(data)"
            }
        }
    }
```

I get HttpClient: {"output":"...","statusCode":200 } from the Api which I want but it fails anyways.

I tried wrap the post request with CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main){
withContext(Dispatchers.Default){}}

But no luck, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating to `Ktor 2.0.0` solved many problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on recent Kotlin and library versions, you should enable the new memory model. Put this in `gradle.properties`

```kotlin
kotlin.native.binary.memoryModel=experimental
```

See [KaMP Kit](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/main/gradle.properties#L23) for an example.

Comment: I didn't need to add this line but migrating to Ktor 2.0.0 solved the problem, Thank you!